# c++ newbie question: How do I cout a vector that is created in a header file?

Tags: function, vector, header-files

The following function is given and lies in a header file:

```
// reads numbers from stdin, one number per line until it detects an empty line
// returns all read numbers in a vector

std::vector<double> read_vector() {
  std::vector<double> result;
  try {
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);)
      result.push_back(std::stod(line));
  } catch (std::invalid_argument&) {
  }
  return result;
}
```

My task is to use this function from the header file to cout the vector.
I wrote a main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "io.hh"

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {      
        for(int i=0; i < result.size(), i++)
        {
             std::cout(result[i], result[result.size()-1]);
        }
            
         return 0;}
```

My compiler says:

```
error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
   21 |     for(int i=0; i < result.size(), i++)
```

What are my mistakes? How do I tell my compiler that I want to use result from read_vector?

Comment: You need to *call* `read_vector` and use its result. Also, if it is defined in a header, it should be `inline`.

Comment: int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {    
    
    read_vector();
    
    for (int entry : result)
    std::cout << entry << std::endl;
    
     return 0;
    }

Comment: It still says 'result' was not declared in this scope

Comment: In the main you function you never called the `read_vector()` function, and result is not defined.
call `std::vector<double> result = read_vector();` before your for loop to assign `read_vector` return value to the result variable in your scope (main function).